# Stop people browsing images on website

Tags: iis, iis-7, permissions

I'm pretty much new to IIS and this is the problem that I'm trying to solve.

I have a legacy web app (complied so not easily changeable) that is running in IIS 7.
This web app displays images to the user of possibly sensitive personal data but if the user views the source the of the page then they are exposed to the url which is viewable directly through any browser.

What I think that I need to do is to remove the folder permissions (where the images live) to stop people directly browsing vewing them and then create another account that has the permissions to view this folder and then associate this newly created account with the application pool that is running the site.

So my questions are would this be the correct way of doing this? And if it is, how would I actually achieve (bearing in mind that I'm a complete novice in IIS and permissions).

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Are users chopping off the file name, e.g. `http://example.com/images/pic01.png` -> `http://example.com/images` to do this?

Comment: No they'll have the complete URL altho the image names are sequential numbers so they can guess at the others

Comment: Forgot to ask, is this an ASP.NET app, if so what version of ASP.NET?

Comment: Nah this is an old classic asp application!

Comment: Woo...nasty :) That said, I still maintain a fairly sizeable legacy ASP blob....and as it happens needed to solve a similar problem. You could solve this with a small ASP.NET HttpHandler app that would work with ASP.

Comment: An ASP.NET HttpHandler app? I could be being a dingbat but what's one of them!

Comment: Give me a couple of hours and I'll pop something onto github...meanwhile I have to get back to unf*cking the nagios upgrade I just did :/

Comment: Ha! You my friend are a superstar!

Comment: Sorry been a tad busy. Anyway...meh...the "simple" idea I had thought of still exposes a way for users to view source and guess the next image id. How savvy are your users? Would they recognise a base64 encoded string? I'm thinking if they so weren't hellish smart you could base64 encode the image file name then using a modified version of this .NET HttpHandler: https://bitbucket.org/kevinkenny/simple-image-handler/src , base64 decode the image name. Move the images to a folder outside the www folders and maybe job done?

Comment: Sorry Kev, I didn't realise that you'd posted a response! I'll have a looky into this and let ya know. 

Cheers matey

Comment: No worries :) The base64 image name would just be an obfuscation, but it might me an obfuscation too far for your userbase to bother working out. Your only other option would be to use a GUID type identifier for your image names which would be fairly unpredictable, but that would may involve some fairly major structural changes to your code which you might not have time for.

Comment: Are these users authenticated users? i.e. they should login before getting access to these images? What type of app is it? Are the images like scans of passports or sensitive docs?

Comment: Hi Kev, the app is an an classic asp one that was written back in the day (I haven't personally seen it). All of the genuine users do have to log in before they can view the images through the application. The images are of number plates and driving licences.